# How to centralize two boxes using HTML, CSS and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to centralize two buttons / clickable boxes, so they look like the following image:

[image]

Here is what I did so far:

css file

```
.container_1 .panel_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.container_2 .panel_2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

HTML file

```
{% block content %}



    <div class="container_1">
        <div class="panel_1">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'left' %}" method="get">
                <input type="submit" value="left" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_2">
        <div class="panel_2">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'right' %}" method="get">
                <input type="submit" value="right" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

How can I modify the code so it reflects the image above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can work out for you? Added some custom containers to hold the styles I wrote to avoid overriding anything on Bootstrap classes, which should not be modified

```css
.main-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container_1,
.container_2 {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.full-btn {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-around align-items-center">
      <div class="col-3 h-50">
        <div class="container_1">
          <div class="panel_1">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'left' %}" method="get">
              <input type="submit" value="left" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block full-btn">
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 h-50">
        <div class="container_2">
          <div class="panel_2">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'right' %}" method="get">
              <input type="submit" value="right" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block full-btn">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, "right" and "left"  do not expand to cover the box fullly. How can it cover the box fullly ?rathe than sticking to the corner

Comment: Okay so you want the `input` to use all of the available space?

Comment: yes sir, on the other hand, how did you control the distance between the center line and the boxes ?

Comment: Since I'm using Bootstrap 4, which is built with Flexbox; I defined each "box" with a class of `col-3` so they use 3 columns out of the 12 available in a row; then I used `justify-content-around` so the boxes are placed with an equal distance between them and the sides of the container

Comment: @Matthew the buttons are now using the full available space; now keep in mind that I'm setting a fixed height with `min-height: 50vh` because on your picture the boxes look large; but you can remove that and the boxes will just use the space of the content inside

Comment: This works well, however the `input {height: 50vh;}` ruins buttons in other pages. Is it possible to only make it effect the .css on those two buttons

Comment: Done, @Matthew just replaced the css rule from `input` to a class `.full-btn` to be more specific

Comment: This is quite incredible! Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicate that you want to rely on Bootstrap in your title, it seems like leaning on Bootstrap 4s flex box utility classes would provide you a pretty simple solution.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="bg-dark text-center">
        
        <form action="#null" method="get" class="mb-0">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">A</button>
        </form>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="bg-dark text-center">
        
        <form action="#null" method="get" class="mb-0">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">B</button>
        </form>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The workhorse classes in this example are `justify-content-center` and `align-items-center`.  The former causes the child elements to be centered horizontally to the width of the container (which in this case is 100% of the width of your page).  The latter does the same but for the vertical axis.

The `h-100` class forces the `row` to take up 100% of the height of the page.  If you wanted to make this *only* take up space after the first 35% of the page you'd probably want to make a custom class that is essentially:

```
.my-custom-class {
  margin-top: 35%;
}
```

And use it there instead.

And if you want your button to take up 100% of the width, please refer to the `.btn-block` class: [Bootstrap 4.x Documentation: Button Sizes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/#sizes)